# Redux-Form: Form level onChange not triggering

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm working with a simple form, and I would like to save it on every change (preferably on blur to avoid many requests). I'm starting off with the `onChange` handler on the form, but it doesn't seem to be triggering.

**Version**  6.6.3

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'OrderForm',  //Form name is same
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  onChange: (values) => {
    console.log('values', values);
  },
})(OrderForm);
```

Comment: I dont think there is a property onChange for redux-forms config property

Comment: No? http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/

Comment: We'll need to see the rest of your code, starting with the `OrderForm` component.